# URL rewriting, PHP templating and the $_GET array

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

I have an index.php file in the top level with other files such as "login.php", "register.php" in a folder called includes. The folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
index.php
includes/
    register.php
    login.php
css/
    style.css
images/
    image.png
```

How can I set the url to something like http://www.mydomain.com/register which then from within the index.php page calls (includes) the register.php page?

Is this the best way to go about it?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is Apache:
Create on root folder file ".htaccess"

```
#.htaccess    
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule /register index.php?mode=register
```

//index.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['mode']=='register')){
      include('includes/register.php');
} 
?>
```

Comment: I get "500 Internal Server Error" I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: remove Options +FollowSymLinks

Comment: It now just says "404 Not Found"

Comment: Root folder has: index.php, .htaccess, includes,css, images?

Comment: Root folder has index.php, .htaccess and the folder includes. Within includes are the folders css, images, and the files register.php, login.php etc

Comment: replace: 
RewriteRule register index.php?mode=register

Comment: I still get the "500 Internal Server Error"??

Comment: if ( isset ( $_GET['mode'] == 'register' ) ) {

Comment: if ( isset ( $_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'register' ) ) {

Comment: I still get the same error, the code you pasted is the same except the spaces.

Comment: That works!!! Except you missed out a "(" before the $_GET['mode'] but it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: if ( isset ( $_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'register' )  {

Comment: Good, now i need to sleep,  don't see the bracket :3

Comment: Can I add more examples to the .htaccess and index.php file i.e for login.php etc or for other pages of the website?

Answer (score 2):

Well, so long as the URL stub  (i.e. /register) is always going to be the same as the file name you want to include, you could do this using Apache's `mod_rewrite`.

However, if you want to change the URL stub to something other than the filename you want to include, why not do this:

```
// Get the URL stub:
$url_stub = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
define('INCLUDE_PATH', 'includes/');

switch($url_stub)
{
    case 'register':
        include(INCLUDE_PATH . 'register.php');
        break;
    case 'login':
        include(INCLUDE_PATH . 'login.php');
        break;
    default:
        // Output whatever the standard Index file would be here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^register index.php?page=register
RewriteRule ^login index.php?page=login
```

index.php:

```
<?php
  include('includes/'.$_GET['pagename'].'.php');
?>
```

EDIT:
For security reasons, see also arnouds comment below.

Comment: I see local file execution vulnerabilities (`include('includes/'.$_GET['pagename'].'.php');`...). What happens if I do `index.php?page=../../../etc/passwd%00` ?

Comment: @arnaud576875: most probably, the user which started the server will not have read access for this file :-) But you are right, you should of course check the $_GET first...

Comment: /etc/passwd is usually world-readable, but that was only and example. This gives anyone the possibility to execute php scripts too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache rewrite rules to do that: (place this in a .htaccess file in the same directoyr than index.php)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/register$ index.php?page=register
```

And in index.php:

```
$pages = scandir('includes');
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'] . '.php';
    if (in_array($page, $pages)) {
        include $page;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method come up with a blank page! Any clues as to what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You can write a .htaccess file with something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?include=$1 [PT,QSA]
```

and the index.php file with:

```
include('includes/'.$_GET['include'].'.php');
```

Of course you can adapt this code to what you need.

Comment: I see local file execution vulnerabilities (`include('includes/'.$_GET['pagename'].'.php');`...). What happens if I do `index.php?page=../../../etc/passwd%00` ?

Comment: `$include = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_GET['include']),ENT_QUOTES,"utf-8");` would correct that vulnerability.

Comment: This has nothing do do with html. How stripping HTML tags avoids me from doing `include=../../etc/passwd` ?

Comment: Btw, the file is passwd, not passwd.php

Comment: try with `../../etc/passwd%00` ;)

Comment: `Warning: include(includes/../../../etc/passwd%00.php)` Maybe I do something wrong, but I can't get this 'work'.

Comment: The %00 is for the url parameter. This decodes to a NULL byte.